# Flutter : Instance of , return Null Json

Tags: flutter

Buen día jovenes, soy nuevo en flutter... tengo la siguiente petición y en el "response" puse un print para verificar su valor y si me regresa el JSON con la información pero cuando ya la quiero pasar a mostrar a la pantalla por ejemplo por medio de un FutureBuilder en snapshot.hasData me retorna null. Adjunto mi código. De antemano gracias!

```
class _VentaPageState extends State<VentaPage> {

Future<List> fetchJSON() async {
 var url = 'http://192.168.1.78:xxxx/api/Cliente/Obtener/1';
 http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
 print(response);
 var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
 return data;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
       iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
         color: Colors.white, //change your color here
       ),
       title: const Text("Venta",
           style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 241))),
       backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(27, 43, 57, 1)),
   body: FutureBuilder<List>(
     future: fetchJSON(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
           // Success case
           return ListView.builder(
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return ListTile(
                 title: Text(snapshot.data?[index]['user']),
                 subtitle: Text(snapshot.data?[index]['team']),
                 trailing: Text(snapshot.data?[index]['id']),
               );
             },
             itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
           );
         }
         // Error case
         return Text('Something went wrong');
       } else {
         // Loading data
         return Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       }
     },
   ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Hiciste un print de `snapshot.data?.length`?

Comment: @padaleiana lo hice ahorita y me tira null

Comment: @padaleiana pude obtener el error y me tira  type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'